# Reload viewController et reinitialize datas

Tags: ios, reload, viewcontroller

I have to reload my view and reinitialize the datas

So I make this code, but it doesn't work. It seem not reload nor reinitialize

```
NSString* typeDePriseEnChargeFinanciere = typePecBouton.titleLabel.text;
NSString* precisezDossierSuiviPar = precisionSuiviTexfield.text;


typeDePriseEnChargeFinanciere = @"Sélectionnez";
precisezDossierSuiviPar = @"";

[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create private variables for your needs in your .h file and then just assign them in a method like this:

your .h file:

```
...
NSString *typeDePriseEnChargeFinanciere;
NSString *typeDePriseEnChargeFinanciere;
...
```

your .m file:

```
-(void)readAllData{
typeDePriseEnChargeFinanciere = typePecBouton.titleLabel.text;
precisezDossierSuiviPar = precisionSuiviTexfield.text;
}
```

And then, whenever you need to read your inputs again, just call your

```
[self readAllData];
```

EDIT:

to reset your button and your label, you need to do this:

```
typePecBouton.titleLabel.text = @"your default text";
precisionSuiviTextfield.text = @"another default text";
```

Comment: I think you don't understand my questions. First i want to reload my view. Then I want to set all the button and textfield to default values.